# не видит файл, ошибка ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Делаю авторизаю\регистрацию, и при подключении по маршруту

```
const regPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public/registration.html');
app.use('/reg', express.static(regPath));
```

возникает ошибка `http://localhost:3000/js/registration.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура файлов и подлкючения такова:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять, где допустил ошибку, толи в маршруте, толи в подключении файла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`404 Error` означает - нет файла по такому пути(файл не найден)

Нода его не отдает, следовательно ты должен его расшарить (share, указать публичную директорию), например: `[project folder]/public`, а уже в публичную папку (`/public`) положить общедоступную папку - `/js`. [читать здесь](https://expressjs.com/ru/starter/static-files.html)

Получится так: `[project folder]/public/js/file.js`

В ноде добавь перед маршрутизацией:

```js
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Если в html прописано так:

```html
<script src="js/file.js"></script>
```

... (+в ноде - как выше) то: У тебя файл будет запрашиваться по следующему пути: `[project folder]/public/js/file.js`, а не `[folder of .html]/js/file.js`

Вообще, я бы на твоем месте почитал как фолдеринг на ноде делается по-человечески.

Визуальные движки + экспресс + модульность + фреймворки. Это всё складывается в приятное\удобное - древо папок

Comment: меня больше смущает, что я указываю маршрут '/reg' для файла registration, а оно в ошибке пытается его найти по пути 'http://localhost:3000/js/registration.js', почему так, где сплоховал?

Comment: @erleug ты указываешь в html путь к файлу уже из публичной папки, т.е. поиск идет тута: `[p_f]/public/*`

Comment: @erleug еще дополнил))0

Comment: спасибо, понял, заработало, только еще вопрос, сломалась моя маршрутизация с главным контентом `const clientPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public'); app.use('/posts', express.static(clientPath));` теперь после добавление строки `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` она отрабатывает по маршруту `/` вместо `/posts`

Comment: в clientPath лежит путь к файлу index.html в папке public

Comment: @erleug 2 прекол публичной папки в том, что если написать `/site/ADMINKA.HTML`, то у тебя она откроется без участия ноды, т.е. любой сможет её пользовать... Намек думаю понятен. Про `view engine` почитай, под `.html` по гайдам `ejs` дается папка `views`, но это не точно, вообще пофег, главное не `public`

Comment: все понял в чем прикол, в последовательности app.use, опустил чуть ниже и заработало все